# suggestions for to improve my python function to parse Wordpress/config.php

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, function

I am writing a python script function to backup Wordpress. As part of the script i wrote a function to fetch database details from the config.php file.

**Working of my function**

function takes Wordpress installation location as an argument and using regex to match db_user,db_host,db_user,db_password from that file, the function will exist if can not find "config.php". **I am using sys.exit(1) to exit from the function is that the proper way to exit from a function?** I am pasting my function code snippet.

```
def parsing_db_info(location):
    config_path = os.path.normpath(location+'/config.php')
    if os.path.exists(config_path):
        try:
            regex_db = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_NAME\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'.group(1)
            regex_user = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_USER\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'.group(1)
            regex_pass = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_PASSWORD\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'.group(1)
            regex_host = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_HOST\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'.group(1)
            db_name = re.match(regex_db,config_path).group(1)
            db_user = re.match(regex_user,config_path).group(1)
            db_pass = re.match(regex_pass,config_path).group(1)
            db_host = re.match(regex_host,config_path).group(1)
            return {'dbname':db_name , 'dbuser':db_user , 'dbpass':db_pass , 'dbhost':db_host}
        except exception as ERROR:
            print(ERROR)
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('Not Found:',config_path)
        sys.exit(1)
```

**AFTER EDITING**

```
def parsing_db_info(location):
        config_path = os.path.normpath(location+'/wp-config.php') 
        try:
            with open(config_path) as fh:
                content = fh.read()
            regex_db = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_NAME\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'
            regex_user = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_USER\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'
            regex_pass = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_PASSWORD\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'
            regex_host = r'define\(\s*?\'DB_HOST\'\s*?,\s*?\'(.*?)\'\s*?'         
            db_name = re.search(regex_db,content).group(1)
            db_user = re.search(regex_user,content).group(1)
            db_pass = re.search(regex_pass,content).group(1)
            db_host = re.search(regex_host,content).group(1)
            return {'dbname':db_name , 'dbuser':db_user , 'dbpass':db_pass , 'dbhost':db_host}

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File Not Found,',config_path)
            sys.exit(1)

        except PermissionError:
            print('Unable To read Permission Denied,',config_path)
            sys.exit(1)
        except AttributeError:
            print('Parsing Error wp-config seems to be corrupt,')
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This should probably be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good enough I am using it.  Thank you, works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, you shouldn't normally use `sys.exit` inside a function like that. Rather, get it to raise an exception in the case where it fails. Preferably, it should be an exception detailing what went wrong, or you could just let the existing exceptions propagate.

The normal rule in Python is this: deal with exceptions at the place you know how to deal with them.

In your code, you catch an exception, and then don't know what to do, so call `sys.exit`. Instead of this, you should:

1. let an exception propagate up to a top-level function which can catch it, and then call `sys.exit` if appropriate
2. wrap the exception in something more specific, and re-raise, so that a higher level function will have a specific exception to catch. For example, your function might raise a custom `ConfigFileNotFound` exception or `ConfigFileUnparseable` exception.

Also, you have put `except exception`, you probably mean `except Exception`. However, this is extremely broad, and will mask other programming errors. Instead, catch the specific exception class you expect.

Comment: I have changed any code according to your suggestions.

Comment: @FujiClado that's a big improvement in terms of catching specific exceptions. If your function is used in exactly one place from within your script, and its a simple script, then using `sys.exit` like that is fine. If you want this function to be more re-usable, then instead of `sys.exit` you should raise custom exceptions, and catch them in a higher level function that calls `parsing_db_info`